# How can I make this Haskell ADT derive Show?

Tags: haskell, printing, show, free-monad

The ADT is the free monad:

```
data Free f r = Free (f (Free f r)) | Pure r
```

I'd like for it to derive `Show` so that I can print it out when working with it. For example, if I have the following:

```
data T next = A next | B next deriving (Show)
aa = Free $ A $ Free $ B $ Pure ()
```

As it is right now, I get the following error if I add `deriving (Show)` to the `Free` ADT:

```
No instance for (Show (f (Free f r)))
      arising from the first field of ‘Free’ (type ‘f (Free f r)’)
    Possible fix:
      use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
        so you can specify the instance context yourself
    When deriving the instance for (Show (Free f r))
```

I'd like for `show aa` to result in a printable string. Is this possible?

Comment: do you need to use `instance Free Show of...`

Comment: Check out [standalone deriving](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Stand-alone_deriving_declarations)

Answer (score 7):

As the error message hinted, you need to use an extension called [`StandaloneDeriving`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/deriving.html#stand-alone-deriving), which lets you specify the constraints on the derived instance explicitly. You also need to enable `UndecidableInstances` to support the constraint you actually need.

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving, UndecidableInstances #-}

deriving instance (Show r, Show (f (Free f r))) => Show (Free f r)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I still had errors. Following the error messages I ended up having to enable three extensions, `StandaloneDeriving`, `FlexibleInstances`, `UndecidableInstances`. Is this to be expected?

Comment: @Ana: Yeah, that looks right. I just forgot to put those into my answer; I'll edit them in now.

Comment: @Ana: Actually, you don't need `FlexibleInstances` since you have `UndecidableInstances`.

Answer (score 2):

A possible alternative approach that avoids `UndecidableInstances`, but that is less widely applicable, is to use the `Show1` class from [prelude-extras](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/prelude-extras/docs/Prelude-Extras.html). This gives you a nice `(Show1 f, Show r)` constraint, but leaves you to write your own (simple) instance.